# sending form data to text file in PHP on live server gives a permission denied error

Tags: php, forms

I'm creating a simple registration form in PHP. When I send form data to text file in PHP on local server it's working well but on live server its giving me a permission denied.

This is my `register.php`

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$phone = $_POST['Place'];
$msg = $_POST['Message'];

$fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a");
$savestring ="First Name= " .$name. " Email id=" .$email. " Phone Number= ".$phone." Message= ".$msg.'/n';
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);?>
```

This is my form :

```html
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" Name="Name" placeholder="NAME" required="">
  <input type="email" Name="Email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="">
  <input type="text" Name="Phone Number" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" required="">
  <input type="text" Name="Place" placeholder="PLACE" required="">
  <textarea name="Message" placeholder="PROJECT DETAILS" required=""></textarea>

  <button type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>

</form>
```

This is working on local server but error is showing on live:

```
Warning: fopen(formdata.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\something.com\register.php on line 7

Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\something.com\register.php on line 9

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\something.com\register.php on line 10
```

Comment: You need to give your script write permissions.

Comment: The error message tells you exctly what is wrong, you just have to read it. PHP (your script) has no writing permissions. Just add writing permissions to it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the PHP user is called `www-data`, you have to give `www-data` writing permissions for the file `formdata.txt`. One way to achieve this is to set the owner to `www-data` via `chown www-data fordata.txt` and change the permissions for the file to 644 (write permissions for owner, reading permission for everyone else) with `chmod 644 formdata.txt`.
Then your script should work just fine.